# Why was the following question deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

The question [An idiom for using power of position to get things done](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332997/an-idiom-for-using-power-of-position-to-get-things-done) looks clear and provides a sample sentence where to use the expression requested. It got four decent answers and a few upvotes, so why was it deleted?

Here is the text for the users  who are not allowed  read deleted posts:

> It is not nepotism as nepotism is possible because they use their power and it is use their power which I want to replace.
>
> Example situation would be getting into someplace by force, like a concert, restaurant or other event.
>
> Another example would be delaying a plane because they can't make it on time.
>
> The politician often ______ and people aren't pleased.
>
> I need a verb idiom only.

Comment: Just a guess here—but it looks as though the poster of the question no longer exists at EL&U (note the blank box where a user icon would normally be, beneath the deleted post). Perhaps all traces of the user's participation at this site are being systematically eradicated? A moderator would know whether that's what's going on.

Comment: @SvenYargs - I thought about that, but still it doesn't look right to me. After all this is a site about questions and answers, not about users. There are a lot of users who have deleted their accounts or are no longer active.

Comment: There have been a spat of questions deleted in the last 24 hours. I know for certain, but there might be more, two user accounts have been deleted along with most of their questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - are you saying that the problem here is not the question   but the user who posted it ? If so I don't see why an on-topic question with answers should be deleted.

Comment: I voted to "undelete" the question just now; I got a popup saying "A moderator has deleted this post and it can not be undeleted".  @tchrist may be able to clarify how this works as his name is in the delete-history?

Comment: The question linked has been undeleted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA See also [this posting](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10197/2085). Thanks.

Comment: Will you please undelete your welcome vs welcomed answer, otherwise I will post an answer myself .

Answer (score 8):

Certain users have been misbehaving so we have deleted certain posts related to this.

Unfortunately your answer got caught up in the clean up. If you believe the question is truly worthy of EL&U then please repost it.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue here is not my answer. I think that once the problematic user has been removed, on-topic questions/answers become anonymous but still valid. There is a lot of anonymous staff on ELU which is still worth reading.

Comment: @Josh Ok then, I'll fix it.

Comment: Another example here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/383517/if-there-is-a-trend-then-who-is-the-leader-inventor-of-the-trend/383520#383520 - ***What's going on?***

Comment: @Josh It's the same answer as before. We're dealing with a complex situation as well as we can. Other approaches would be even less tenable.

Answer (score 3):

There hasn't just been one question closed there have been perhaps *dozens*.

In addition, some of these questions had three or more answers posted, and they were also upvoted. I'm not going to post the links because the users responsible for this shambles would be easily identified.

I comprehend the rationale behind the deletions, it's a punishment. The accounts associated with the users should not earn rep from cheating.

But what about those users who posted original answers in good faith? Should their efforts be swept aside too? Does [one or two bad apples spoil](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/384023/44619) the whole site?

Is there no better solution than deleting?

Comment: It's a complex situation in this case, one which we are not at liberty to discuss.

Comment: @tchrist I appreciate that the situation is messy, through no fault of the administrators but someone else will post a question asking what happened to their answer, or to someone's question. I think the situation has to be aired out in the open and users be informed of a decision that affects their participation.