# Deleted Upvoted and Popular Question: Why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, policy

### The question is now Undeleted

<sub>I am very grateful to tchrist, who undeleted the post.

P.S. Several answers, consisting of one liners, have been deleted because they fail to reflect the site's standards that is expected today.</sub>

> [Is there a word for someone who really has their act together?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123468/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-really-has-their-act-together)

I happened to remember this question and the many answers it received, and I wanted to find it again today. I needed a word or expression that fitted this description. Impossible. The question has been deleted.

Luckily I had posted an answer, so with a "search operator" that I discovered on SE Meta, I managed to track it down.

For users who do not have 10K the post is not be visible, so let me describe it briefly. The question attracted 68 upvotes and 1 downvote, and 32 answers were posted. The highest upvoted answer (+81 and -9) suggested *hoopy* and *frood*. The second and third answers earned 35 and 20 upvotes respectively. Out of 32 answers, only three earned 0 upvotes.

This is the question:

> **Is there a word for someone who really has their act together?**
>
> Someone who has their time well-managed, is focused, works out, has ambitions,
>   eats right. Not necessarily *success*, but there's a kind of trait that leads to it, that I can't quite put my finger on.
>
> There's strong overlap with people who are competitive or are overachievers,
>   but it's not exactly the same thing. "In the zone" is close, but I'm looking for a more long term or permanent kind of thing — the opposite of a *slob* or *slacker*.
>
> Maybe there isn't a word, but there should be.

The post was closed by a mod for being "too broad" in August 2013, **two years later it was deleted singlehandedly by a different mod**. I don't want to name names, besides their names are visible to 10K users, and I'm pretty sure there must be a rational explanation for the deletion.

SE dictates that an answer or a question deleted by a mod, can only be undone by another mod. So casting a vote to undelete the question above will resolve nothing.

- I understand that the question was too broad, that kinda makes sense, but I disagree with its deletion. I would like to know what the SE policy and criteria for deleting questions is, especially posts which have been upvoted and received numerous answers.
- Why was this question deleted–no reason was provided–and is it possible to undelete it in the not too distant future?

---

CLARIFICATION

This needs to be stressed; **the question was closed by one mod, not by voting. The question was deleted by a different mod, not by voting.**

The Help Centre page says:

> Moderators can delete any question, and users with sufficient reputation can cast delete votes on closed questions.

It fails to mention that users cannot cast their votes to undelete a question previously deleted by a mod. If the question closed is “extremely off-topic” (e.g. proofreading), has attracted more downvotes than upvotes, has no answers or answers which have no upvotes, then THOSE are the very questions which should be deleted by the mod team. But a question with 68 upvotes and 32 answers? Can we not agree it is not the same as a wall of text asking users to proofread it? The request is in a completely different league. This is not your typical low-quality question.

---

### How many closed questions are there on EL&U?

Currently, there are [22,208 closed questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3Ayes). According to the canonical SE Meta post unearthed by  tchrist♦  (specific information which is sadly missing from the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)) we learn the following:

> Therefore, **you should generally view a closed question as one that has been nominated for deletion.** If you think there's a good reason for it to stick around, say something.

This is me saying something. This is me asking why a mod deleted a popular and useful question without explanation.  Was it unintentional? And finally, can this decision be reversed today?

<sub>Please upvote this post if you believe the aforementioned question should be undeleted. Thank you. UPDATE: Currently there are three users who have cast their undelete votes. The question cannot be undeleted by non-moderators, but heartened, I too have cast my vote to undelete. Every little bit helps...</sub>

Comment: The mod who deleted it doesn't usually do much mod stuff. It may have been a slip of the finger. His fingers have slipped before, complete honest errors, on different issues.

Comment: @DanBron Yes, I *know* this has happened before. But deleting this question, when it was already closed, doesn't make sense. I mean if it was accidental, which I'm not ruling out, wouldn't the mod immediately realise their mistake and undo the deletion? Deleted posts appear purple, there's an actual change in colour. But yeah, it was, hopefully, accidental.

Comment: I just went through it, its answers and comments, and I don't see anything that would have given that particular mod offense, so far as I'm familiar with his motivations and predilections. Perhaps he deleted it and didn't understand, or deleted it and didn't quite know how to reverse that action. Anyway I agree the Q should be undeleted, at a minimum, and I'm glad you raised this Meta-Q. You must have had the Q bookmarked to find it again like this, after it was deleted?

Comment: @DanBron no, I didn't. I just remembered this SWR question, I remembered liking it and wanting to compile a personal list, but then I couldn't find it. I recalled that I had posted an answer, so I searched on Meta, and found the following "search operator" which is the following: `deleted:yes` . It displays all your deleted post in one page, very handy. Great little script, or whatever you computer nerds call it. :>)

Comment: @DanBron imagine one day, four or five years from now,  discovering your Swedish ax answer is deleted. Gone.  Because a mod accidentally deleted the "...word beginning with “y”? question. It could happen, shouldn't there be some form of safeguard against this. Unless, there was a specific need  to delete the post.

Comment: I think you have triggered the safeguard: alerting the community and other mods, politely but firmly, with a dossier of evidence supporting your case, in Meta. I am glad you did so. I'd not seen the Q before, but now that I have, I enjoyed it. I also think it should be undeleted (I +1'd this Q for that reason about 30 min ago).

Comment: +1 What Dan Bron said. I was about to say the same when I saw the mod's name over there. "It may have been a slip of the finger." That mod is usually not involved in moderation activities. The diamond is sort of honorary, (although it was earned by an election).

Comment: The deletion, two years afterwards, was simply a clerical act, removing a closed question (closed questions, if there is no activity to improve them, by design of the SE system, should be deleted eventually). The concern, if you want this question to be preserved, is whether the question is worthy of reopening. Can you make a case for the question at hand to be reopened? If so, and you can get enough people to vote on it (here on meta) I'm sure that a mod can, clerically, undelete it to allow voting to reopen.

Comment: But note that nobody spent time trying to fix the problems with the question that caused it to be closed in the first place.

Comment: The focus is about a question deleted by a single mod, a question that was highly upvoted. Aren't upvotes an indicator of quality? two days ago Dan Bron's wrote:  [*Stack Exchange makes it easy to find the good stuff, and ignore the bad stuff. Ultimately, when you see a highly upvoted or highly downvoted post, you don't care why. You care the most people agree, and that takes a the impossible burden off you to evaluate every single post. Voting, up and down, is what makes this work.*](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10477/44619)

Comment: If upvotes indicate quality, why was this post deleted? It had 68 upvotes. If this is just a routine clerical task then every closed question, in theory, is in line to be deleted. This policy has to be written in the Help Centre. Users should be informed.  @Mitch would you agree? That this information is missing from the Help Center. A fairly vital piece of information, if I say so myself.

Comment: `But note that nobody spent time trying to fix the problems with the question that caused it to be closed in the first place` @Mitch. Yes, well I would cast my vote to undelete the question to begin with but I can't. And judging by the comments there are two or even three other users who would like to do the same.

Comment: @Mari-Lou 1 - tchrist addressed closing vs deleting and help center. 2- your focus is on deleting, but I'm saying that you should be concerned about closing because those votes are about the content, which is presumably what you really care about.3- Why deleted or closed when so highly voted? Because there are three kinds of voting: question up/down votes, an closing, and question deleting. Three different situations/3 diff kinds of assessment. Usually correlated, not identical. Everyone can vote, highrep people can vote to close, higher to delete. Higher rep expected to think long term

Comment: To clarify, are you simply asking 'why' about all this, are you asking for people's opinion on the particular SWR question, are you asking to please undelete or reopen or vote to do so, or something else or some combination?

Comment: Mods are *part* of the community, not separate from it.

Comment: @tchrist  Fair enough, you're absolutely right, but as Mitch commentated you have "superpowers", and we expect each one of you to use those super-powers wisely. If you can singlehandedly delete questions then start with the questions that have no upvotes and no answers. The really bad stuff.

Comment: Moderators have binding votes in all things, by design. We don't vote—we decide. We are specifically directed to take unilateral action when we deem it prudent. If you start tugging at all the threads you find sticking out of the site in which a single moderator carried out this or that specific action, you will not be happy, for that is a hole with no bottom: there are many tens of thousands of those here. You will also be unhappy when you discover how we don't always remember after a year or five exactly why we did something.  At some point, you really do have to trust our judgement.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I don't remember the question being put on hold, I was a newcomer, probably didn't feel confident enough to raise a debate about it on meta. When a post is deleted, along with your answer you are not notified, you don't see 10 rep vanishing mysteriously from your profile. That only happens when a user's account is deleted, you immediately see a drop in your rep when that happens.. As for the reopening procedure, that's what I'm doing here. I cannot cast a vote to undelete or reopen it.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I only found the question because I had posted an answer. If I hadn't, the OP would have been impossible to find. I can view any user's deleted answer if the question is not *deleted*, but when a question is deleted, and you haven't posted an answer, the only way of tracing it is to have saved its URL address, or favourited it.

Comment: Yes indeed @Mari-lou A that's what I assumed: the original closure of the question somehow escaped your notice, or else you'd have raised this same concern at the time and voted for reopening.It's obviously a highly upvoted question with multiple upvoted answers (at least one of which was highly upvoted). So raising this type of meta question is the proper way to bring it to the moderators' attention? Which you have done, and I hope they take some action. I also appreciate your raising larger concerns about the closure & deletion of questions;and the answer by RaceYouAnytime is very pertinent.

Comment: @EnglishStudent regardless of whether I think it should be reopened, after all, it attracted 32 answers, there's not much more you could add. You don't think a question with 68 upvotes and that many answers will get deleted. You think, OK, it's closed but it's in the archives, not the end of the world. No, instead a closed question, even a good question, can be deleted by a single individual. Anyway, now "some" users know that questions and answers are also ephemeral, not just comments.

Comment: Very true. And all closed questions remain visible, along with all the answers and one can even post comments... From a purely self-centred perspective, I should *shudder to think* that my hard-workingly crafted answer(s) would disappear if the *question* got deleted!

Comment: I have upvoted your specific request for undeleting this question. I hope you will also try to get it reopened later.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - mods are reluctant to  reverse their actions (for obvious reasons), what about re-asking  the question making it "less broad"?

Comment: @Josh and yet they undeleted a question which had far fewer upvotes... https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10190/why-was-the-following-question-deleted. I'm not posting anything on the main site because if I did,  it would only get downvoted and closed for being off-topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think that question was undeleted by users, it didn't require mods intervention.

Comment: @Josh no I'm quite positive it was deleted and undeleted by tchrist because.... a user had abused the system, see my answer, a whole batch of questions were deleted by him. If users had voted to undelete the question then it must have been closed by five users. So what was the reason for closure and then its deletion? You don't know because the community didn't close it! That's why you asked. You saw a dip in your rep, yes? Otherwise how did you find out it was deleted?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - There is a degree of discretion in what mods do, and I think they are just doing thier job. If the user base disagrees, they have their own discretion too in VTC, VTR etc. If this question will not be reopened, it can be re-asked and I doubt it will end up closed and deleted again.

Comment: @Josh if it's me who asks, you can be damn well certain, some users will rush to close the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What? Your Qs are always positively received. I still sometimes think of your exquisite title "Eww... has it crossed the pond yet?"!

Comment: @Mari-LouA You've asked 100+ questions and probably a handful of them got closed, but that's just normal. We are not hell-bent on closing your questions.

Comment: @DanBron and NVZ I am referring to the users who downvoted *this* question on meta, and those who upvoted tchrist's. If I were to copy and paste the original it might be interpreted as goading. If I wrote a similar question 1) it would never receive the same assorted suggestions 2) if it did receive twenty or more solutions the same users who downvoted this meta question would close it  for being "too broad". This is what I meant. Moreover, I am not going to post a equivalent question it would suggest that I am resigned. I'm not.

Comment: well, the end of this sad story is that I'll never ask other questions on ELU, probably I've already asked too many.

Comment: @Josh oh, don't be silly. Ask the questions that interest you and have a little faith in users. Yes, you will get the odd downvote. Yes, you will get that same user posting irrelevant and sarky comments. So flag that user until you're blue in the face. I think, generally speaking, your questions are much much better received by the "hardcore" members than your answers. That's my unbiased impression. P.S This comment is staying.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - well, the same holds for you, but you are still refraining from asking or answering. Also this comment is staying.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - well, you are giving in, don't blame me for doing the same.

Comment: Actually those 4 votes were to "reopen", not "undelete". I reopened it with the final vote. But it still remains deleted.

Comment: @NVZ it clearly says **undelete**. Before reopening a question, which is not what I am asking for, you have to first undelete it. EDIT: I already knew it was impossible to undelete it, but I was encouraged by the votes. It shows the community does care.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The linked question is now reopened, but stays deleted. See https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/123468/revisions

Comment: Would you agree to leaving deleted all the one-liner non-answers consisting of say less than 500 characters of original text? I have no further patience for [this crap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ODmU.png) whether on that question or anywhere on our site, and it very much bothers me that people are cool with it. If you won't agree to that, I cannot support undeletion.

Comment: @tchrist  It's a compromise which I am glad to accept. And may I ask that you reverse the CW status too, seeing as the number of answers will be culled.

Comment: @tchrist leave ["go getter"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123471/44619)? That was one of the answers I liked most. I know, it's just a one liner but it does have a link. A user could expand the answer easily...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Nope. All one-liners would stay deleted, including those with copypasta. This is not a twenty-questions game of guessing cool crossword puzzle answers. We are better than this. I don't care if it has +999: a one-liner suggestion is crap. It isn't an expert answer.

Comment: @tchrist Oh, all right then.

Comment: Done and buried.

Comment: I know, just upvoted JR's answer. Thank you!! Thank you :)

Comment: I don't disagree on reversing the deletion of our honorary mod, but the question should still be closed because it doesn't explain how the request word is to be used.

Answer (score 7):

## What’s the policy on deleting closed questions?

Closed questions should ultimately be either deleted or else fixed up so they can be reöpened. The one referenced in this question simply went the former route: deleted two years after closure. Here’s another example of [one of those](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30244/2085). And also [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/94100/2085).

All three of these accord with the guideline that closed questions should in the long run end up being deleted from the site.  Upvotes are not a solid criterion for non-deletion. We have around 35k deleted questions as of this writing, very many of them with upvotes. Most should stay that way; sometimes some of them should not, so it’s a valid question to raise here.

The question is still whether it should stay deleted and closed — and given that it’s closed, why shouldn’t it be deleted?

While there can always be exceptions, Stack Exchange has actually provided some general guidance for these situations.  Over on Meta Stack Exchange, there’s a [canonical answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65770/153355) to this provided by  one of our august Community Managers:

> #### Do closed questions get deleted automatically after some time?
>
> *If* there's no activity, questions with a score <=0 can be [deleted automatically after a (fairly generous) period of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408).
>
> [Also, once closed, users with >= 10K reputation points can vote to delete it after 48 hours, and users with 20K can vote to delete immediately...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean). Moderators can and sometimes will delete questions at any time - closed questions are often deleted on sight as part of a cleanup effort.
>
> Therefore, you should generally view a closed question as one that has been [nominated for deletion](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/). If you think there's a good reason for it to stick around, say something.

So our guidance from the Powers That Be is that you should generally view a closed question as one that has been nominated for deletion. Let’s keep that in mind.

## QED?

To make an argument for undeletion, one must argue that the [referenced deleted post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123468/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-really-has-their-act-together) really is the kind of question that adds to our growing library of **expert answers** on our “site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”.

That argument has not been made — quite possibly for good reason. In any event, it ***remains to be demonstrated***. If that attempt ***is*** made, one would do well to consider these points:

- Why would we wish a closed question undeleted if we still intend to leave it closed?
- Before someone raises the possibility of a lock, we don’t much care for historical locks and this question does not seem to merit one.
- It’s marked Community Wiki, so it’s not like anyone’s rep would be affected were it to be undeleted.
- It has 32 answers, which are all over the map.
- Its quondam protection did little to stem the tide of random answers.

---

<sub>Perhaps if there were eventually a Stack Exchange site whose *raison d’être* were to create a home for these sorts of English-language guessing games and requests for writing advice — call it EnglishRequests.StackExchange, shall we? — then we could entertain the notion of someday sending it thither. Yet even new sites deserve to create their own community standards about what is and what is not on-topic there. (And even if we wished to, it would take an employee to migrate it because it’s far too old, and I’m nearly certain they would decline the request.)</sub>

Comment: Perhaps some culling of answers might be in order, but I think this, from the Meta question, counts as an argument "that it's the kind of question that adds to our growing library ...": "**I needed a word or expression that fitted this description.**" (I think we'd agree that the OP is a "serious English language [enthusiast]").

Comment: Somehow the deleted Dalai Lama joke with 160 upvotes was asked in ELL by one of our senior mods 2 years later and it has the same score there. https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/224/29183

Comment: The question which I am referring to was not deleted by the community,  but by a single mod. The community, in theory, can vote to undelete a post any time they want or see fit, but this is denied when a post has been deleted by a mod. I did not put forward any argument to reopen or undelete the OP because I was unsure whether the deletion was accidental or not. Until I know the truth, how am I supposed  to persuade you that the OP was useful? But it was, to *me*. Can you say for certain that it will not interest or help any future visitor?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm still gathering input right now; there are pings outstanding that may help if answered.

Comment: In the meantime, if the deletion was not accidental, this means any mod can decide to delete any closed question without telling anyone. I don't consider this procedure to be democratic or correct.  Why did the mod choose to delete this particular post? Did (s)he feel it was worthless? Or was it a mistake?

Comment: @Mari-LouA If closed questions were deleted by tchrist, I'll accept that because tchrist is a very experienced user in moderation activities even before earning the diamond status. But regarding the deleted question under consideration, I don't think that that mod deleted it after careful consideration. My best guess; it was a slip of fingers or something.

Comment: These are all really good meta-_meta_ points about closing deletion to help decide about the particular question. I think there should be some content supplied by people on both sides, pro/con about whether to reopen the question according to the points laid out here. To your first point, deletion is simply the next stage after closing. If enough people _really_ want to have new answers to the question or use it as a reference, then I think it is only an administrative move to undelete.

Comment: Maybe you should take this to meta.SE Since you seem to be bothered by the general workings of how the system is designed (mods are supposed to have super-powers).

Comment: What does **mod removes wiki** mean? Does it mean a mod can reverse a Community Wiki status? i.e. none of the answers automatically become CW because the limit of 30 answers was surpassed. That limit no longer exists, so nowadays we can get questions with over 30 answers and no one loses any rep.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Was the question closed by the community, or unilaterally? I wouldn't fault a moderator for deleting a question that was inactive and closed for more than 2 years. Closures are done by experienced community members (3000 rep), up-votes (15 rep), not so much.

Comment: @ColleenV It was originally closed by a mod back when the SWR requirements had just been refocused, under those guidelines. Two years after that,  another mod deleted it in response to a flag on it. It would have otherwise taken 10 normal delete votes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I think that's right. It used to trigger automatically under various circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

Based on advice from [the help center on question deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions), as well as from these SE Meta discussions...

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
- [When should I vote to delete a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-a-question/59054#59054)

...it seems well-established that a closed question "*that cannot be improved and reopened*" and has been inactive for a long period of time *should* be deleted.

So it seems to me that the most relevant question is whether this question ought to be ***closed*** when many other single-word-requests that appear equally broad and have more than one possible answer seem to survive.

Some examples might be these:

- [What term means “one who enjoys learning”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163232/what-term-means-one-who-enjoys-learning) (9 answers)
- [Word for “only caring about oneself ”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65472/word-for-only-caring-about-oneself) (14 answers)
- [What's a word for avoiding a question with a generic (fake) answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/whats-a-word-for-avoiding-a-question-with-a-generic-fake-answer) (17 aswers)

These three examples were easily selected by random trial and error, and I have a hard time seeing what makes them less "broad" than the question referenced by the OP.  All three appear to me to have zero close votes and are protected with many "guessing-game" style answers.

I would propose that EL&U might not be adhering to a strict standard for closure on single-word-requests.  Should more be closed, or should less?  Should the one being discussed here be undeleted and nominated for reopening?  Those are questions the community (and moderators) should stick to a consistent standard on, for the sake of fairness to all questions.

Comment: Consistency is good; notice how when the question was closed, the Too Broad close-reason read: *“There are either **too many possible answers,** or good answers would be too long for this format. 
Please add details to narrow the answer set
or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.”* Its 32 answers sure feels like it’s “too many possible answers”, eh? Beyond that, most answers are not “in several paragraphs”: they’re one-liner suggestions, sometimes with dictionary copypasta, and certainly not the high-quality expert answers that will help future visitors to our site.

Comment: The [following question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397550/what-is-a-long-complicated-word-for-adding-many-unnecessary-details-to-make-a-s) is broad (28 answers and counting) and, arguably,  off-topic. The majority of answers are not high-quality expert answers either. Most suggestions are copy and paste answers from a dictionary. Shall we tell the users who posted an answer that if the question does get closed, their contributions could, one day, be wiped out by a single individual? Shall we tell them that? One of those 4 close votes is mine, I am now going to retract it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: If you think it necessary to tell users that low-quality answers to a question we decide we don't want are liable to be deleted, you have a low opinion of users' research skills.  If you are suggesting that bad posts should always be retained, then why?

Comment: @tchrist that makes sense.  But *number of answers* seems like a dangerously arbitrary measure of whether a question should be closed (and in this case deleted).  Is being *too broad* at the whim of users who answer with copy-paste one-liners?  Shouldn't the fact that "most" of the answers were low-quality make their count *less* relevant to the usefulness of the question?

Comment: You say and I quote: _ *I would propose that EL&U might not be adhering to a strict standard for closure on single-word-requests.* _  However this is a message not for moderators but for inconsistently (close)voting members, and does not apply to single-word-requests alone but to all questions. Very pertinent answer overall, @RaceYouAnytime!

Comment: @EnglishStudent true and good point, but since in this case the question was closed by a moderator, not by voting, the point is somewhat directed at both.  That's why I wrote *Those are questions the community (and moderators) should stick to a consistent standard on*

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime I get you; but to be fair to moderators, their action to close a question is rare and usually has good reason. The community (I mean individual members) need to be far more consistent in casting close votes, which is not just a privilege but a responsibility. The crucial thing is that you can see hundreds of questions *very similar* to closed questions, actually remaining open.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I agree with all of that.  Your point that many similar questions remain open is indeed the crucial thing.  I've posted a separate Meta question opening the floor for discussion on when single-word-requests are too broad because I think the standard is especially inconsistent with that particular tag.  They're very distinct from other types of questions.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Many SWR questions have no true answer and therefore remain unresolved. But it is a hobby for many and greatly increases participation & site traffic at ELU. What *really* complicates it is that a disproportionately huge number of upvotes and reputation points are earned by everybody including myself from our answers to single-word-requests.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I'm not really suggesting that single-word-requests should necessarily be reduced, just that the standards for when they are or aren't closed ought to be consistent and as objective possible.  Then it would be easier to tell whether the question in this post should have been closed or not.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime It certainly requires serious discussion, so I await the community response(s) to your related meta question.

Comment: Psst...the question is undeleted. Yay! Thank you for your answer, you made a huge contribution. Thank you!